# Lower bound for a strictly decreasing function

Tags: analysis

Let us give the following definition:

A function $\rho \colon [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ is said to be of class $\mathcal{L}$ if it is continuous, strictly decreasing and $\lim_{s \to \infty} \rho(s) = 0$.

Here is my question:

Let $\rho \in \mathcal{L}$ be given. Does there exist a function $\underline{\rho} \in \mathcal{L}$ such that $\underline{\rho} (s^2) \leq \rho(s)$ for all $s \geq 0$?

Comment: Did you mean $$\underline{\rho} (s^2) \leq \rho(s)$$ or $$\underline{\rho} (s^2) \leq \underline{\rho}(s)$$

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I rephrased the question. Still, I meant $\underline{\rho} (s^2) \leq \rho(s)$.

Comment: If you define: $\underline{\rho} (s) = \rho(\sqrt{s})$ for all $s \geq 0$ ... doesn't that work trivially here?

Comment: I suspect it does. I just wanted to check it with an expert!

Comment: OK, well... I am not one :) but seems to me like it works.

Comment: :) Anyway, many thanks for your help.